# Qt 5.1 for Android issue when running app on device(Can’t find necessary libs)

Tags: android, qt, deployment

I installed latest Android-SDK, NDK and Ant.
I downloaded three Android apis(10,17,18) and developed a simple qt app for android

Below is my deployment tries

First I tried to deploy api level 10 emulator(app deploys but shows a blank screen)
Second I tried to deploy api level 17 emulator(app deploys and runs smoothly)
Third I tried to deploy api level 10 device running android 2.3.6(app deploys but shows blank screen)

On my third try application output shows:

```
E/Qt (14265): Can’t create main activity E/Qt (14265):
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
/data/data/org.qtproject.example.sampleapp/lib/lib—Managed_by_Qt_Creator—plugins_platforms_android_libqtforandroid.so
(No such file or directory) E/Qt (14265): at
org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method) E/Qt
(14265): at
dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
E/Qt (14265): at
java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:80) E/Qt (14265):
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:132) E/Qt
(14265): at
org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.createBundledBinary(QtActivity.java:366) E/Qt (14265): at
org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.extractBundledPluginsAndImports(QtActivity.java:386)
E/Qt (14265): at
org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.startApp(QtActivity.java:436)
```

What is problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you use Ministro or uploaded the libs in the device? What Qt Creator version are you running?

Comment: Please check [link](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/30761/) for solution